# NextJS Dynamic Component not rendering out in SSR even when SSR: true

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-components

Perhaps I misunderstand how the next/dynamic components work... but when I have code like this:

```
const RealContent = dynamic(() => import('./RealContentComponent'), {
  loading: () => <span>...placeholder Not Real Content...</span>,
  ssr: true,
})
```

I expect, on the server side rendered HTML file that the `<RealContent/>` component would render out what's in `./RealContentComponent`

But when I do a `next build` and then look in the `.next/server/pages/RealContent.html` page, all I see is the span with ...placeholder Not Real Content

shouldn't the `ssr: true` force it to render out the actual component during build time. (there's nothing in the RealContentCompnent that requires the client.)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's our code. I made an example repo showing how it works...
https://github.com/Chenzo/dynamic-ssr-test

if you have SSR: True it does render it out when `npm run build`